# hoverinfo displaying over bars in plotly histogram R

Tags: r, plotly, histogram, r-plotly

I'm trying to create an histogram with plotly, but when I define the 'hoverinfo' information, it displays the information over the bars and not 'inside'.
[image]

```
diamonds %>% plot_ly(x = ~cut, color = ~clarity, hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~carat)
```

I tried to use `add_histogram()` as well, but nothing seems to work. What should I do?

Comment: This is strange - when I run the same command, the plot looks correct (i.e. the hover text only appears when you hover over the bars. I wonder if it's related to the version of plotly you are running (try updating?) or the way you are viewing. What if you try `p  <- diamonds %>% plot_ly(x = ~cut, color = ~clarity, hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~carat)` and then `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, "p.html")`. Does the problem persist when you open the html file?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of plotly, since I've installed it one week ago.
Even if I try to save it as html, it still appears that numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was intrigued by your comment that you had the most recent `plotly` version, so I downloaded it and I could replicate your issue. It looks like there has been a change in the way the default `text` argument is treated in `plotly.js`, see [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-js-2-0/53675):

> textposition for bar traces now defaults to auto so if you want to use text without it appearing on the figure, you’ll need to explicitly set textposition="none"

Unfortunately, when `type="histogram"`, there is no `textposition` argument. The way to fix this in your case is to replace the `text` argument with `hovertext`:

```r
library(plotly)
diamonds %>% 
    plot_ly(
        x = ~cut, 
        color = ~clarity,
        type = "histogram",
        hoverinfo = "text", 
        hovertext = ~carat
    )
```

[image: This should resolve the issue.]

Comment: omg it really worked, thank you a lot!!! <3